# Why is $\textbf{E}[X + Y \mid X,Y] = X + Y$?

Tags: statistics, conditional-expectation

Intuitively, it seems obvious, but I am struggling to prove it for the case where $X_1,...,X_n$ are continuous random variables. I am aware that $E[c(X)|X]=c(X)$. So how would one show that $E[c(X_i)|X_1,...,X_n]=c(X_i)$ and that $E[c(X_i)+a(X_j)|X_1,...,X_n]=c(X_i)+a(X_j)$ for $i,j=1,...,n$?

The reason I am asking is that, given a linear regression model $y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_i + u$ where $y,x_1, x_2, u$ are random variables, it is often said that $E[y|x_1,x_2]=\beta_0+\beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2 + E[u|x_1,x_2]$

Answer (score 3):

According to the conditional expectation's properties, one gets:

\begin{align*}
\textbf{E}[X + Y | X,Y] = \textbf{E}[X + Y | \sigma(X,Y)] = X + Y
\end{align*}

That is because both $X$ and $Y$ are $\sigma(X,Y)$-measurable and consequently the same applies to $X + Y$.